# How can i inflate three layouts in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, layout, row, inflate

I have a custom listView in which i want to inflate three different layouts.

I have seen many questions but they are all for odd and even position but in my listView the layout that should be inflated to the listView depends on other condition and its dynamic like

if (i == 0) i get the first Layout to be inflated and if (i==1) second one and so on,

The variable "i" is equal to the value I would be getting from my main Activity.

```
public class SocialListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {


private Activity activity;
private List<Item> items;
private Item objBean;
private int row;
private int i;


public SocialListAdapter(Activity act, int resource, List<Item> arrayList) {
    super(act, resource, arrayList);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.activity= act;
    this.items = arrayList;
    this.row = resource;

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;


}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    objBean = items.get(position);


        i = objBean.getI();


            if (view == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



        if(i == 0){

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);

        }  else if (i == 1){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, null);
        }
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
```

I tried this code but dint work...

I was getting an error when i scroll through the listView arrayoutofbondexception

Comment: For starters, if you want to support 3 different layouts, it doesn't make sense to return 2 in `getViewTypeCount()`. Also, `getItemViewType(int position)` should return a value unique to the type you want to display in the row given by `position`. In other words: if your type count is 3, then you should only return 3 different values in that method, not *n*.

Answer (score 1):

`getItemViewType` has to return a number from 0 to `getViewTypeCount`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> comments; 
    Context mContext;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> comments) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.comments = comments;       
    }


    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        String item = comments.get(position);

        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {

            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {

                //GET View 1
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_comment2, null);

                v = viewGroup;
            } 

            //Fill Data for Ist view 
            TextView comm = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            comm.setText(item);

            return v;


        } else if (getItemViewType(position) == 1) {


            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {

                //GET View 2
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_comment1, null);


                v = viewGroup;
            }

            //Fill Data for IInd view 
            TextView comm = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            comm.setText(item);

            return v;

        } else {

            //GET View 3
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_comment3, null);


                v = viewGroup;
            }

            //Fill Data for IInd view 
            TextView comm = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            comm.setText(item);

            return v;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {     
        return comments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return comments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {       
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() { 
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if(position == 0)
            return 0;
        else if (position == 1)
            return 1;
        else 
            return 2;
    }
}
```

You can optimize and make your scrolling smooth by defining view holder :
Try [this](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) also

in getItemViewType you can set your condition where do you want to show which type of view.

Answer (score 0):

use "if(position==0)" inside getView method

Answer (score 0):

You can check the condition and inflate the layout that you want.
Here is the example. I have three category depending on it I inflate different layouts.

```
   public class ApplicationAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context cntx;

        /**
         * 0 - featured 1- Top rated 2- other
         */
        private int whichCategory;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * 
         * @param context
         * @param iwhichCategory
         *            0 - featured 1- Top rated 2- other
         */

        public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int iwhichCategory)
            {
                cntx = context;

                whichCategory = iwhichCategory;

            }

                @Override
        public int getCount()
            {
                return entApplications.size();
            }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
            {
                return null;
            }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
            {
                return 0;
            }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                if (convertView == null)
                    {
                        // This a new view we inflate the new layout
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cntx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        if (whichCategory == 0)
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.featured_app_grid_item, parent, false);
                        if (whichCategory == 1)
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_app_grid_item, parent, false);
                        if (whichCategory == 2)
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_app_grid_item1, parent, false);
                    }
            }
    }
```